# Changing the value of the numeric elements of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to change the value of the numeric elements of a column without having to create a helper column to convert to numeric

Something like this put it throws an error

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: `false` must
>   be type double, not character.

```
foo = c(1, 2, 3) 
bar = c(1, "AB", 3)
df = data.frame(foo,bar,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df%>%
  mutate(bar=if_else(!is.na(as.numeric(bar)),as.numeric(bar)/100,bar))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if_else` is type sensitive.  We can have only a single `class`.  So, both the `true` and `false` parameters should be of the same `class`.  In the OP's code, one is `numeric` and another is `character`.

```
df %>% 
   mutate(bar = if_else(!is.na(as.numeric(bar)), 
           as.character(as.numeric(bar)/100), bar))
```

Note: A regular `ifelse` (`base R`) would still work without changing the type

---

Another option is to filter the elements that have only numeric values and convert it to `numeric` and do the division

```
i1 <- grep("^[0-9.]+$", df$bar) # or the is.na(as.numeric route
df$bar[i1] <- as.numeric(df$bar[i1])/100
```

Comment: Or `mutate(bar = coalesce(as.character(as.numeric(bar)/100), bar))`